# Mudar para proximo input automaticamente

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Fala galera!

Tenho dois *inputs* no formulário e gostaria de saber como eu faço para que quando o *input1* estivesse preenchido ele automaticamente mudasse para o *input2*.

Esses são os *inputs*, no caso tem um limite de 5 dígitos:

```
<input type="text" id="input1" maxlength="5" required>
<input type="text" id="input2"  maxlength="5" required>
```

Comment: Faltam algumas informações pra poder definir uma resposta para a sua pergunta. Por exemplo, o que define que seus inputs já estão preenchidos? Por exemplo, são todos selects? Possuem algum tamanho de caracteres que definem que estão preenchidos?

Sem uma regra pra entender em que momento o input está 'preenchido' não há como solucionar o problema.

Comment: Bem vindo Romulo, coloque o seu código até o momento detalhe melhor a pergunta.

Comment: Facilite também postando como está seu formulário no momento e o que já tentou fazer para resolver o problema.

Comment: coloquei um exemplo de como seriam os inputs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Crie uma classe em comum para os inputs, capture a entrada do input ativo, defina uma condição para ir para o próximo input, após validar a condição, pegue o próximo input e chame o evento focus.

```
$(".inputs").keyup(function() {
    if (this.value.length == this.maxLength) {
        $(this).next('.inputs').focus();
    }
});
```

[Referência](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10539258/5360385)

Answer (score 0):

Você pode criar uma função para focar no próximo input ao pressionar enter bastando apenas passar o id por parâmetro em uma função onkeyup.

Exemplo:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function PressEnter(nextinputId){
    if(event.keyCode == 13){
        document.getElementById(nextinputId).focus();     
        return false;           
    }
}

</script>

<input type="text" id="input1" maxlength="5" onkeyup="PressEnter('input2');" required>
<input type="text" id="input2"  maxlength="5" required>
```